# Scilab "Warning adding a matrix with the empty matrix will give an empty matrix result."

Tags: scilab

- I am a new user of Scilab (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69059245)).
- I define a simple piece-wise function and get a confusing warning when I use the function (`"Warning adding a matrix with the empty matrix will give an empty matrix result."`).
- Do you see where my mistake is?

---

```
function  y = myTest(t) 

// First Part
y(find(t < 0)) = 0; 

// Middle Part
y(find(0 <= t & t <= 1)) = 1; 

// Middle Part
ti3 = find(1 < t & t <= 3);
y(ti3) = -1*t(ti3) + 2; 

// Middle Part
y(find(3 < t & t <= 4)) = -1; 

// Middle Part
ti5 = find(4 < t & t <= 6);
y(ti5) = +1*t(ti5) -5;

// Middle Part
y(find(6 < t & t <= 8)) = 1; 

// Last Part
y(find(8 < t)) = 0; 

endfunction

myTest(1)

t = 0:0.1:10;

plot(t',myTest(t))
```

[image]

*(Plot for `myTest(t)` using `t = 0:0.1:10`.)*

[image]

*(Confusing warning.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the `find()` call and use logical indexing (the logical expressions yield boolean vectors with the same size as t and can be used as indexes) :

```
function  y = myTest(t) 

// First Part
y(t < 0) = 0; 

// Middle Part
y(0 <= t & t <= 1) = 1; 

// Middle Part
ti3 = 1 < t & t <= 3;
y(ti3) = -1*t(ti3) + 2; 

// Middle Part
y(3 < t & t <= 4) = -1; 

// Middle Part
ti5 = 4 < t & t <= 6;
y(ti5) = +1*t(ti5) -5;

// Middle Part
y(6 < t & t <= 8) = 1; 

// Last Part
y(8 < t) = 0; 

endfunction

myTest(1)

t = 0:0.1:10;

plot(t',myTest(t))
```

However, after reading your post on StackExchange, if your velocity is always piecewise affine, then you could use `interpln`, which can be further derivated (see SO other post) or integrated with `ode`:

```
function out=rhs(t,y)
  out = interpln(ty,t);
end

ty=[0 1  3 4 6 8
    1 1 -1 1 1 0]
t=linspace(0,8,1000);
h=sqrt(%eps);
d=(interpln(ty,t+h)-interpln(ty,t))/h;
p=ode(0,0,t,rhs)
plot(x,interpln(xy,x),x,d,x,p)
```

See `ode` and `interpln` scilab help pages for the meaning of their arguments (if not explicit enough above).
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Regarding the `find` function, I was following a tutorial: https://www.matrixlab-examples.com/scilab-piecewise-function.html. Is there any benefit in using the `find` function? And I still don't understand why using the `find` functions leads to the warning message.

Comment: Using `find` or logical indexing is equivalent, athough the latter is more elegant. The warning message occurs with both approaches and is due to the call `myTest(1)` which yields empty matrices in `t(i3)` and `t(i5)` (and addition/substraction of empty matrices with any matrices yields an empty matrix)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So the first part of your answer is not about the warning message, it's about a cleaner code, right? But the second part of your answer resolves the warning message I assume (haven't tested it yet).

Comment: Yes, exactly. The second part of the answer gives the simplest way (in Scilab) to handle a piecewise affine function, and won't give the same empty matrix warning when using a scalar argument.